# How to run wpf(c#) application by service account and integrated security

Tags: c#, wpf, t-sql, connection-string

i want to run my WPF aplication with service account...

Maybe i dont understain situation currectlly but i want to use `integrated security=true;` in my connectionString and run application localy but with different account. Is that even possible?

Lets say my windows login acc is `testAcc` and my service account is `SAtestAcc`.
SAtestAcc has execute rights on database1 and testAcc doesnt have any on same database1...

So how do i specify in my connectionString that i am trying to connect to database with AStestAcc, but **not** by specifying `username` nad `password` in connectionString but by using `integratedSecurity=true`.

Again: Is that even possible?

Thanx

Comment: Later on i found this tut on how to do it and it is excelent: http://freshclickmedia.co.uk/2008/11/programmatic-impersonation-in-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrated security means that it takes the current security context and uses this. So to appear as another user you would have to authenticate with username and password and use impersonation. Here is a good article on that I have referred to a few times.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the application under the user context of SAtestAcc.

See the below on instructions for how to do this in Windows 7.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html